# underscore.js .before function implementation

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Can someone explain me how is the _.before function implemented as i dont really understand why the internal `times` variable keeps track of every function call. Shouldn't it be in local scope and reset every time like normal functions ?

Code for _.before function :

```
  // Returns a function that will only be executed up to (but not including) the Nth call.
  _.before = function(times, func) {
    var memo;
    return function() {
      if (--times > 0) {
        memo = func.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      if (times <= 1) func = null;
      return memo;
    };
  };
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of a concept named `closures`, the returned function in your example "remembers" the environment in which it was created. In that case, it remembers both `times` and `func` arguments, even though it's returned.

Read more about closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 0):

The key is `func.apply(this, arguments)` makes the anonymous function recursive.  The scope of `times` is outside the inner anonymous function.  When the closer is called `--times` is executed, with the scope of `times` being the `before` function.